# How to recursively crawl the url subdirectories?

Tags: html, node.js, web-crawler, subdirectory

**Hi everyone, i'm trying to program a web crawler that takes in the main URL of a website and crawl the subdirectories of the website. Ive been stuck at this for quite some time. Can somebody help me with this? Thank you very much in advance!**

Here is an example output that i am trying to get:

Title of https://www.dintaifung.com.sg/index.php: Din Tai Fung Singapore

Title of https://www.dintaifung.com.sg/about.php: Din Tai Fung - About Us

Title of https://www.dintaifung.com.sg/...: Din Tai Fung - ...

and so on ...

```
var Crawler = require("crawler");

var c = new Crawler({
maxConnections : 10,
// This will be called for each crawled page
callback : function (error, res, done) {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        var $ = res.$;
        // $ is Cheerio by default
        //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
        console.log($("title").text());
    }
    done();
}
});

// Queue just one URL, with default callback
c.queue('https://www.dintaifung.com.sg/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get [a `callback` for each page crawled](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler#callbacks). The incoming `res` parameter describes each page.

Try something like this for your callback function.

```
callback : function (error, res, done) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        const $ = res.$; 
        const title = $("title").text());           //find the page's title
        const url = res.request.uri.toString();     //get the fetched URL
        const display = `Title of ${url}: {title}`; //make your display string
        console.log(display);                       //display it
    }
    done();
}
```

`$` let you use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)-like operations to search the body text ("traverse the  Document Object Model")  of the page retrieved by the crawler.  The raw body text shows up at `res.body` if you want to see it. But keep in mind it looks exactly like View Source ... for the page that you crawled.

**Tip:** May I suggest you debug this with `maxConnections: 2` rather than `10`? Crawling can put a heavy load on a site, and crawling with a new app mighty make it worse.